# Finding the smallest $k$ such that $f(x)$ divides $1-x^k$ where $f(x)$ is over $\mbox{GF}(2)$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

One technique is iterative that is to assume alpha as the root and solve for a higher exponent ($x$) until $\alpha^{x} = 1$.

Is there any other technique?

Comment: $k$ is sometimes called the _period_ of a polynomial. See Chapter 6 of Berlekamp's _Algebraic Coding Theory_ for methods for finding the _period_ of a polynomial. I thnk your method assumes that $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Thanks and is it necessary for f(x) to be irreducible?